# Postgresql how to find item between datetime and in time zone

Tags: sql, postgresql

How could I query for a list of Products created_at between 12:01am Pacific on January 20 2015 and 11:59pm Pacific January 25 2015. All times stored in database are in UTC.

Would it be something along the lines of

```
SELECT * FROM products 
WHERE  products.created_at >= '2015-01-20 00:01:00'  AT TIME ZONE 'PST'
AND    products.created_at <=  '2015-01-25 23:59:00'  AT TIME ZONE 'PST'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could specify the UTC offset in your timestamps. US/Pacific is 8 hours behind UTC during Standard Time. So:

```
SELECT * FROM products 
WHERE  products.created_at >= '2015-01-20 00:01:00-08'
AND    products.created_at <=  '2015-01-25 23:59:00-08';
```